# What is the significance of Alara's gift to Capt. Mercer?

Tags: the-orville

In the third episode of season 2 of The Orville, Alara gets a gift for Capt Mercer as a goodbye present. The gift isn't revealed until the end of the episode. Capt Mercer opens the box and pulls out a jar of pickles and smiles. What is the significance of pickles? I must have missed or am not remembering some kind of inside joke.

Comment: is this Season 2? because 3rd episode of Season 1 is about Bortus's child being born a girl and a debate on forcing a sex change operation while Season 2 Episode 3 starts with Isaac breaking Alara's arm and her being told she has to return to her home planet (didn't get to see the entire episode but the next episode suggests she ended up staying)

Comment: Yes season 2. Forgot to add that.

Comment: I believe this was a reference to season 1 where he occasionally would ask her to open a jar of pickles (stuck doors, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, Alara is the strongest member of the *Orville*'s crew but, initially, rather than concentrate on her duties as Security Chief the emphasis on her character was based on her strength to open stuck doors etc. and, on at least one occasion, open a jar of pickles.

In the very first episode, Mercer asks her.

> "Alara. You want to open this jar of pickles for me?"

She makes this look easy and he then says

> " I loosened it for you."

..to make it seem as though he didn't really need her help.